# How to check blank value of group result ($2) in Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl regex given below which is returning url which is inserting within video tag if doesn't have video tag.

As you can see `$2` is added within video tag in below regex. but I want to check blank or null of $2. if $2 is blank then display some other text like "No Video" etc.

So please help how to check returned `$2` value for blank and display some other text in that case.

```
$text =~ s#(^|\s|\>)((http|https)://www.hulu.com/watch/([a-z0-9\/\-]+))#$1\[video\]$2\[\/video\]#isg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of possible way (but I'm **strongly** *recommend not to use regular expression for this*):

```
my $good_text = "some text>http://www.hulu.com/watch/sdfsdf";
my $bad_text = "some text>http://www.hulu.com/watch/";

$good_text =~
s!(^|\s|\>)((?:http|https)://www.hulu.com/watch/([a-z0-9/-]*))!$1\[video\]@{[($3) ? $2 : "No video"]}\[\/video\]!isg;

$bad_text =~
s!(^|\s|\>)((?:http|https)://www.hulu.com/watch/([a-z0-9/-]*))!$1\[video\]@{[($3) ? $2 : "No video"]}\[\/video\]!isg;

print "Good '$good_text'\n";
print "Bad '$bad_text'\n";


$good_text = "some text>http://www.hulu.com/watch/sdfsdf";
$bad_text = "some text>http://www.hulu.com/watch/";

#below is the right way for such things -- using /e switch and function call    
$good_text =~
s!(^|\s|\>)((?:http|https)://www.hulu.com/watch/([a-z0-9/-]*))!check_result($1, $2, $3)!isge;

$bad_text =~
s!(^|\s|\>)((?:http|https)://www.hulu.com/watch/([a-z0-9/-]*))!check_result($1, $2, $3)!isge;

print "Good '$good_text'\n";
print "Bad '$bad_text'\n";

sub check_result {

    my ($text, $url, $id) = @_;

    if ($id) {
        return $text . "[video]" . $url . $id . "[/video]";
    }
    else {

        return $text . "[video]No video[/video]";
    }
}
```